# How to make an app that makes people post anonymously

Tags: android, blogs

I want to create this kind of android app for my school. It's very simple, it's an app that would let anyone post in a wall. So basically kind of like twitter, except everyone's post would be anonymous. However, it needs intense moderation, before you post what you want to post, it would undergo a moderator's permission to post. It also moderates how many posts you can do in a single hour, and it needs to work on both ios and android. In summary, it's a freedom wall, anything you want to say, can be sent to moderators, and they would determine if it's okay to post it. Hope you can help me, cheers!

Comment: we dont write any code for you. you need to get started before anyone will help you.... oh, and welcome to stack overflow. ill give you a hint. if the same user doesnt need the same "id" then all you need to do is give that user a random string name when you post. break it down into steps....its easy yes, but it may be a challenge if you just jump into it without research or prior experience.

Comment: yeah you're right. I'll start working on it with my friend, thanks for the help with the hint, I'm already sure it's a huge help from here on out.

Answer (score 1):

Youn can take a look at what similar apps are doing and try to copy their way with your own modifications and ideas. (the Jodel app is very close to what you describe)